# List add a ref to string object

Tags: c#, list

Is there any option to do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Student
{


    public string PassPort { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<string> AllProperties { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        AllProperties = new List<string>();
        AllProperties.Add(ref PassPort);
        AllProperties.Add(ref FirstName);
        AllProperties.Add(ref LastName);
        AllProperties.Add(ref Message);


    }

}
```

so when I change the `AllProperties[0]` it will change the `PassPort` string variable???

Comment: You want AllProperties[0] to call the Propert "PassProt" ? if so you should you reflection

Comment: i am using DataTable to show info and i wanna doing that by index i get

Comment: i am doing execl datatable and i need string as properties
but the message properties is optional so i wanna make sure that only the relevent properties is fullfill and not enter null to properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what it is you are after, but you might be able to use an indexer:

```
class Student
{
    public string PassPort { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0:
                    PassPort = value;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // etc.
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the use that like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        student[0] = "PASS";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am doing execl datatable and i need string as properties
but the message properties is optional so i wanna make sure that only the relevent properties is fullfill and not enter null to properties